# display date and time when content has changed in div (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use Vanilla JS; to display the date and time when an html element is updated.

So for instance when the content changed within my:

```
<li class="active"></li>
```

I know jQuery has quick methods to identify via selectors, i.e.

```
$('li.active').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    alert('changed');
});
```

but i need a plain vanilla JS solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect changes in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

Comment: You can still use that. Attach it to the element instead of the document and that will isolate it.

Comment: it's better to subscribe upstream to the JS stuff that actually changes the markup, instead of sniffing mutation side-effects, which are fragile and performance-robbing.

Comment: There is at least [one answer that demonstrates using this at the element level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50493861/215552)...

Answer (score 1):

Use a mutation observer to watch the list item instead of watching the document as a whole.

```js
// The item we want to watch
var watch = document.querySelector('.active')

// The new observer with a callback to execute upon change
var observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
  console.log(new Date().toUTCString())
});

// Start observing the element using these settings
observer.observe(watch, { childList: true, subtree: true });

// Some random test function to modify the element
// This will make sure the callback is running correctly
setInterval(() => {
  watch.innerHTML = Math.random() * 1000
}, 1000)
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

Most jQuery code has a similar counterpart available. The `$('li.active')` can be replaced with `document.querySelectorAll('li.active')`. This gives you all elements matching your selector. The `bind` call would be achieved by iterating over the elements and using `addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function(event) { … })`.